# Generating set for wreath products

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, wreath-product

Let $G$ be a finite $n$-generated group and $p$ be a prime not dividing the order $\vert G\vert$; let $C_p$ be the cyclic group of order $p$. According to results by A. Lucchini (Rend. Sem. Mat. Univ. Padova 98 (1997) 67--87 and Arch. Math. 62 (1994) 481--490) the wreath product $C_p^{n-1}\wr G$ is also $n$-generated. Can one write down explicitly a set of $n$ generators of this wreath product (involving generators of $G$)?

Edit: what about the case $n=2$? One would need a 2-generating set for
$C_p\wr G\cong \mathbb{F}_pG\rtimes G$ in terms of a 2-generator set of $G$.

Comment: If I remember correctly, then you cannot write them down explicitly. The proof is a counting argument. You consided all inverses images in the wreath product  of the generators of $G$ and show that there are too many of these for them all to generate proper subgroups of the wreath product. You would need to look at the paper for more details.

Comment: @Derek Holt. Thank you, I looked into the papers, they use lots of representation theory, the first also homological algebra. I see no chance to figure out concrete generators from there. But the results are  more general, I thought maybe something is known if the base group is more 'concrete'.

Comment: It's difficult to see how you could do anything very explicit if all you know about $G$ is that it is $2$-generated.

Comment: @Derek Holt: as a concrete example, I would be interested in the sequence of 2-generator groups $G_1=C_2\times C_2$, $G_2= C_3\wr G_1$, $G_3= C_5\wr G_2$ ... .